# RavenDB embedded session.Load hang for a while

Tags: c#, ravendb

I need to use a embedded RavenDb for one of my project.  I installed the Nuget Package "RavenDb.Embedded".  After that, the following dlls have been added to the project:

- Raven.Abstractions
- Raven.Client.LigthWeight
- Raven.Database

My entity class for storing data:

```
public class TagLastRead
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastReceiveDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a RavenConfig class as follow:

```
public class RavenConfig
{
    private static IDocumentStore _store;
    public static IDocumentStore Store
    {
        get
        {
            if (_store == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "IDocumentStore has not been initialized.");
            return _store;
        }
    }

    public static IDocumentStore Initialize()
    {
        _store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            ConnectionStringName = "LocalTagReads"
        };
        _store.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";
        _store.Initialize();
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), Store);
        return _store;
    }
}
```

My app.Config file have the following line under "connectionStrings"

```
<add name="LocalTagReads" connectionString="DataDir = ~\Data" />
```

My class that needs to acces RavenDb looks like this

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        RavenConfig.Initialize();
    }

    public DoStuff(TagInfo value)
    {
        using(IDocumentSession session = RavenConfig.Store.OpenSession())
        {
            TagLastRead t = session.Load<TagLastRead>(value.Tagname);
            if (t == null)
            {
                t = new TagLastRead();
                session.Store(t,value.Tagname);
            } 
            t.LastReceiveDateTime = value.Time;
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The "Data" directory is created with some files in it and sub directories.  The problem is when the following line of code is hit

```
TagLastRead t = session.Load<TagLastRead>(value.Tagname);
```

The program hang forever without any error in the output.
By hitting the pause button in debug, I can see that it is stuck in MemoryStatistics class.

**EDIT**

I'm using version 3.0.30037

When invoking `IndexCreation.CreateIndexes` or `session.Load` or `session.SaveChanges` I have the following exception in the output log

- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
- A first chance exception of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Connection.ErrorResponseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

After waiting for a while I have the following error

System.InvalidOperationException: Query failed. See inner exception for details. ---> System.TimeoutException: Operation timed out after: 00:01:41.1979667 ---> System.AggregateException: AsyncHelpers.Run method threw an exception. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.Implementation.HttpJsonRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<b__d>d__10.MoveNext() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Implementation\HttpJsonRequest.cs:line 226

Comment: What build are you using? If you stop in the debugger, what is the stack trace you see?

Comment: @AyendeRahien I've added the details to the post.  Yesterday, it was hanging forever, but today it takes about 5-10 seconds and it continue, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you try this in commnad line app?

Comment: Just found out that I forgot the add the Serializable attribute to my class, that solved the issue.  Thanks @AyendeRahien.  You can add a response and I'll set it as the answer since you help me find out.